# Dependency Injection - Whats the best way to decouple my logic class from dependencies in web environment? - services calls, cookies, urls etc

Tags: c#, javascript, browser, dependency-injection

In my logic classes i have ajax calls to web services, i store stuff in cookies, get info from the uri query string and display messages to the user.

What would be a best practice to decouple my logic class from those dependencies?

My environment:
I'm developing with SharpKit ( C# to javascript compiler ) so i'm writing in c# and eventually my code compiles into pure javascript and runs only on the browser (no server side code).

At the beginning i was thinking of wrapping them as a 2 repositories: 1 for ajax calls and the others for browser all interaction(cookies, urls, messages, etc..)

Right now it looks something like that (without DI):

```
public class CustomersScreenController
{    
    public CustomersScreenController(
        Services services,
        CookieHelper cookieHelper,
        UriHelper uriHelper)
    { ... }    
}
```

Does it make sense i'd put all browser's stuff in one repo? 
On the other hand, Cookies and Query Strings seems to me like another data source...

What do you think ?

Another question:
How would you layer this kinda app ?

ajax calls seems to be the Data Layer
controllers are the Logic Layer
and BrowserStuff (cookies, url, messages) the UI Layer?

Currently it works with MVC like this:
Controller makes the ajax calls and fills the Model with data,
Model is one way databinded to the View that has all the display objects(text boxes, grids, etc..)
View takes care of view logic like rendering, hovering, clicks etc.. and fires events into the controller.

Eventually I'd love to test the controllers so I want to start using DI

Comment: What are `Services`, `CookieHelper`, and `UriHelper`? Concrete classes or interfaces?

Comment: Since you're writing a client-side application, why don't you write it directly in Javascript with AngularJS instead? AngularJS has built-in DI, an MVCish architecture, and support for TDD/unit testing.

Comment: @MarkSeemann those are currently concrete classes and i want to change that situaltion and put them behind abstractions since i dont wanna know where the data came from i just want to have something like CustomersRepository.
about moving to Angular, I'd love to give it a shot but its not my decision, I just work here :)
and to tell you the truth, maintaining a c# code for such a big client-side application is actually pretty nice

Comment: As a first step, you could attempt to extract some interfaces from those concrete classes, but it's probably not going to be of much benefit: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/02/Interfacesarenotabstractions If you'd 'love to test the controllers', a much better option is to develop the code using TDD. With unit testing, 'eventually' usually means 'never'.

Comment: @MarkSeemann thanks for the link, i'll dig into it soon. 
I have to point out that i'm refactoring some existing code.
I was thinking to abstract services with  ICustomerRepository and to use ICustomersBrowserContext to include methods calling cookies and url...
the question is if i should abstract it in a way that knows the details behind the abstraction ?
ICustomersBrowserContext tells us the data comes from the browser.
maybe it should it all go into ICustomerRepository ?
but then it would deal with 3 data sources (services, cookies, url)..
thanks for the help, Dan

Comment: As a general rule, the less the abstraction 'leaks' knowledge of the implementation, the better. However, a leaky *name* is most likely to be the least of your concerns. At this point, I think the best advice I can give is to extract the interfaces from what the client needs, not from what the concrete class exposes. As [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#](http://amzn.to/19W4JHk) explains, interfaces belong to the consumers, not the services.